# Finding and deleting words in a string sentence

Tags: c++, string

As an assignment, I have to write a function in C++ that deletes a word in a sentence. We are given the sentence itself as a string `std::string sentence` and the number of a word to be deleted `int place`.

There can be multiple spaces between words and sentence can end and begin with spaces.

For example: `DeleteWord("Fox   jumped  over lazy dog", 2)` 
should return: `"Fox     over lazy dog"`.

The problem is that I can only use std::string size() and resize().

I also should delete only the word, not the spaces around it.

I've written some code, but the output is not right: I am putting all words in an array and then deleting the one in an argument but the whitespaces are a big problem as they are being put in the array as well, thus I am not being able to delete and print them correctly.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks!

My code so far:

```
std::string DeleteWord(std::string sentence, int place){

    std::string retvalue;

    long long wordcounter = 0;
    long long spacecounter = 0;
    long long spacescounter = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<sentence.size(); i++){
        if((sentence[i]==' ') && (sentence[i+1]!=' ')) spacecounter++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<sentence.size(); i++){
        if(sentence[i]==' ') spacescounter++;
    }

    std::string words[spacescounter+1];

    while(i<sentence.size()){
        if(sentence[i]!=' '){
            words[index] += sentence[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            index++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    sentence[place-1] = ' ';

    for(int i=0; i<=index; i++){
        retvalue+=words[i] + ' ';
    }

    return retvalue;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205909/discussion-on-question-by-f33tl0v3r-finding-and-deleting-words-in-a-string-sente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the words in the char array by checking the spaces and I delete the words by changing the '\0'(end string) position o by shifting the array

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
string DeleteWord(string a,int index)
{
    int length=a.size();
    int pos;
    int word=1;
    char* s;
    s=new char[length];
    strcpy(s,a.c_str());
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' ' and i!=0 and s[i-1]!=' ')
            word++;
    }
    if(index>word)
    {
      delete [] s;
        return "error";
     }
    else
    {
        if(index==word)
        {
            pos=0;
            for(int i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if(s[i]==' ')
                {
                    pos=i+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            s[pos]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
            int wl=0;
            char pre=' ';
            word=0;
            pos=-1;
            bool found=false;
            for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
            {
                if(pre==' ' and s[i]!=' ')
                {
                    word++;
                    if(word==index){
                        found=true;
                        pos=i;
                    }
                }
                if(found==true)
                {
                    if(s[i]==' '){
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                        wl++;
                }

                pre=s[i];
            }
            for(int i=pos; i<length; i++)
                s[i]=s[i+wl];
        }
        string f=string (s);
        delete[] s;
        return string(f);
    }

}
int main()
{
    string str="Fox   jumped  over  lazy dog";
    cout<<DeleteWord(str,4)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The function has to return string, thus it has to be std::string type. Also, the first argument has to be std::string as well, not a char. These are the rules of the task.

Comment: I changed the code. This should respect your constrains.

Comment: I have edited the code to remove the variable-lenght array

Comment: @ThomasSablik Now the code should work for every input.

Comment: But when the function ends the variables should destroy.

Comment: @ThomasSablik btw now the code should avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to count the spaces or words. You don't have to store the words in an array.

Iterate over the sentence and decrement `place` if the previous element is a space and the current is a non-space. If `place` is 0 you have to skip the word. Else copy the string into returned string. As I said in the comments it's as simple as one loop, one variable, 3 if conditions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string DeleteWord(const std::string &sentence, int place){
    if (sentence.empty()) {
        return std::string();
    }

    auto isPreviousSpace = std::isspace(sentence[0]);
    if (!isPreviousSpace) {
        --place;
    }

    std::string retvalue;    
    for (const auto &c : sentence) {
        if (isPreviousSpace && !std::isspace(c)) {
            --place;
        }
        if (place != 0 || std::isspace(c)) {
            retvalue += c;
        }
        isPreviousSpace = std::isspace(c);
    }

    return retvalue;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << DeleteWord("Fox   jumped  over lazy dog", 2);
    // Output is: "Fox     over lazy dog"
    return 0;
}
```

A C++98 solution without `std::isspace` and without const ref argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string DeleteWord(std::string sentence, int place){
    if (sentence.empty()) {
        return std::string();
    }

    bool isPreviousSpace = sentence[0] == ' ';
    if (!isPreviousSpace) {
        --place;
    }

    std::string retvalue;    
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < sentence.size(); ++index) {
        if (isPreviousSpace && sentence[index] != ' ') {
            --place;
        }
        if (place != 0 || sentence[index] == ' ') {
            retvalue += sentence[index];
        }
        isPreviousSpace = sentence[index] == ' ';
    }

    return retvalue;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << DeleteWord("Fox   jumped  over lazy dog", 2);
    // Output is: "Fox     over lazy dog"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Is there any way I could exchange "auto" and "const auto &c : sentence"? I am coding in C++98 and would like to have simplier solution that that as I don't understand it and it does not compile at all.

Comment: I added a C++98 solution without `std::isspace`

Answer (score 0):

Find starting index and ending index of the word need to be deleted, i call it `s` and `e` respectively, the result will be: `sentence[0:s-1] + sentence[e+1->sentence.size()-1]`. I assume input value of place will be valid (greater than zero and equals to or less than number of words in the sentence). You can try with my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

pair<int,int> startAndEndIndexOfWord(string sentence, int place){
    pair<int,int> startAndEnd;

    int currentWordIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<sentence.size();i++){
        //meet a word
        if(sentence[i]!=' '){
            currentWordIndex += 1;
            if(currentWordIndex==place){//if it is the word need to be delete
                startIndex = i;
                //find ending index
                endIndex = sentence.size()-1; //just a default value
                for(int j=i+1;j<sentence.size();j++){
                    if(sentence[j]==' '){
                        endIndex = j-1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                startAndEnd.first = startIndex;
                startAndEnd.second = endIndex;
                return startAndEnd;
            }
            else{
                i+=1;
                while(sentence[i]!=' ') i++; //ignore the current word
            }
        }
    }
}
string deleteWord(string sentence, int place){
    string result;
    pair<int,int> startAndEndIndex = startAndEndIndexOfWord(sentence,place);
    for(int i=0;i<startAndEndIndex.first;i++){
        result+=sentence[i];
    }
    for(int i=startAndEndIndex.second+1;i<sentence.size();i++){
        result+=sentence[i];
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    int place = 5;
    string sentence = "Fox   jumped  over lazy dog";
    string result = deleteWord(sentence,place);

    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I cannot use any other header files than <string> and <iostream>, so <map> is not available to use.